# How to suppress complex numbers in the calculation of the square root of a positive semi-definite matrix using scipy.linalg.sqrtm()

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, square-root

Say I have a matrix A (this matrix is quite large so I did not specify this here), and applying `scipy.linalg.sqrtm(A)`, I get the following output matrix which contains complex numbers:

```
array([[ 64.06444692+8.96831017e-44j,  -6.28785787+1.57772181e-30j,
         -9.15586255+3.94430453e-31j,  -9.00198187+1.97215226e-31j,
         -7.71376342+7.88860905e-31j,  -6.28785787-1.97215226e-30j,
          2.97380679+0.00000000e+00j,   1.29893642+7.88860905e-31j,
          1.31682879+1.57772181e-30j,  -0.351662  +7.88860905e-31j,
         -9.15586255-6.90253292e-31j,   1.29893642+1.97215226e-31j,
          2.36636534+4.48415509e-44j,  -0.57657211+9.86076132e-31j,
          0.39917092-2.95822839e-31j,  -9.00198187-3.94430453e-31j,
          1.31682879-1.57772181e-30j,  -0.57657211-1.97215226e-31j,
          2.36648045+4.48415509e-44j,   0.28162   +1.97215226e-31j,
         -7.71376342-7.88860905e-31j,  -0.351662  +0.00000000e+00j,
          0.39917092+6.90253292e-31j,   0.28162   -3.94430453e-31j,
          1.21720917+3.58732407e-43j],
       [ -6.28785787+0.00000000e+00j,  37.43772093+0.00000000e+00j,
         -4.54039284+6.61744490e-24j,  -4.70636743+3.30872245e-24j,
         -2.75237216+6.61744490e-24j,  37.43772062-2.64697796e-23j,
         -5.74532523-2.25694915e-36j,  -3.84385982-1.32348898e-23j,
         -4.65882698+3.30872245e-24j,  -2.99673941+2.64697796e-23j,
         -4.54039267+0.00000000e+00j,  -3.84386008+1.32348898e-23j,
         -0.51143448+3.00926554e-36j,  -6.96326972+3.97046694e-23j,
          2.14326501-3.97046694e-23j,  -4.7063676 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -4.65882709-3.30872245e-24j,  -6.96326948+6.61744490e-24j,
          0.72851489+1.69271187e-36j,   2.15291748+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.75237195-1.32348898e-23j,  -2.99674005-2.64697796e-23j,
          2.14326499+2.64697796e-23j,   2.15291766+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.2575331 +0.00000000e+00j],
       [ -9.15586255-3.76158192e-37j,  -4.54039278+8.27180613e-24j,
         32.72911898-4.96308368e-24j,  -1.85021394-1.65436123e-24j,
         -2.53702773+9.92616735e-24j,  -4.54039273-1.48892510e-23j,
          1.83872342-1.12847458e-36j,  -1.86092192-6.61744490e-24j,
         -4.29572397+9.92616735e-24j,   1.09027491-2.64697796e-23j,
         32.72911818+0.00000000e+00j,  -1.86092174+6.61744490e-24j,
         -9.24894513-9.40395481e-38j,  -4.93062942+3.30872245e-24j,
         -2.40960071+2.31610572e-23j,  -1.85021376+0.00000000e+00j,
         -4.29572395-6.61744490e-24j,  -4.93062949+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.40879764+6.58276836e-37j,   1.34936369+1.98523347e-23j,
         -2.53702818-5.79026429e-24j,   1.090275  +1.32348898e-23j,
         -2.40960075-1.98523347e-23j,   1.34936389-1.65436123e-23j,
          0.47563635+3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -9.00198187+5.17217514e-36j,  -4.70636737+3.30872245e-23j,
         -1.85021382+1.65436123e-23j,  32.3679699 -3.30872245e-24j,
         -2.62837621+1.65436123e-23j,  -4.70636767-3.30872245e-23j,
          1.64638076-7.52316385e-37j,  -4.2159266 -2.97785021e-23j,
         -0.86792129+6.61744490e-24j,   0.99791227-5.29395592e-23j,
         -1.85021388-1.15805286e-23j,  -4.21592618+2.81241408e-23j,
          1.17619748+6.01853108e-36j,  -3.93042699-6.61744490e-24j,
          1.17237038+6.61744490e-24j,  32.36796885+6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.86792107-6.61744490e-24j,  -3.93042699+6.61744490e-24j,
        -10.37559738+1.12847458e-36j,  -2.60535084-5.62482817e-23j,
         -2.62837615-1.65436123e-23j,   0.99791236+4.63221143e-23j,
          1.17237044-6.61744490e-24j,  -2.60535074+5.62482817e-23j,
          0.59574761-3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -7.71376342+4.51389831e-36j,  -2.75237237+1.98523347e-23j,
         -2.53702781+3.30872245e-24j,  -2.62837605+3.30872245e-24j,
          5.69625179+1.32348898e-23j,  -2.75237175-1.98523347e-23j,
         -0.56750495+1.12847458e-36j,   1.03933818-1.32348898e-23j,
          1.0435955 -6.61744490e-24j,   0.3804354 -1.32348898e-23j,
         -2.5370281 -3.30872245e-24j,   1.03933817+1.32348898e-23j,
          0.42008941+3.00926554e-36j,   2.3668576 -6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.24619723-5.29395592e-23j,  -2.62837631+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.04359542+0.00000000e+00j,   2.3668577 +8.27180613e-24j,
          0.34120424+3.76158192e-37j,  -0.2668792 -5.29395592e-23j,
          5.6962513 -6.61744490e-24j,   0.38043513-6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.24619695+3.97046694e-23j,  -0.2668791 +4.30133919e-23j,
         -1.24019775+0.00000000e+00j],
       [ -6.28785787+0.00000000e+00j,  37.43772062-2.64697796e-23j,
         -4.54039267-1.32348898e-23j,  -4.7063676 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.75237195-3.30872245e-24j,  37.43772093+2.64697796e-23j,
         -5.74532523+7.52316385e-37j,  -3.84386008+0.00000000e+00j,
         -4.65882709+0.00000000e+00j,  -2.99674005-2.64697796e-23j,
         -4.54039284+1.98523347e-23j,  -3.84385982+0.00000000e+00j,
         -0.51143448-3.00926554e-36j,  -6.96326948-2.64697796e-23j,
          2.14326499+3.97046694e-23j,  -4.70636743-6.61744490e-24j,
         -4.65882698+0.00000000e+00j,  -6.96326972+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.72851489-1.78675141e-36j,   2.15291766+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.75237216+3.30872245e-24j,  -2.99673941+1.32348898e-23j,
          2.14326501-3.30872245e-23j,   2.15291748-1.32348898e-23j,
          0.2575331 +0.00000000e+00j],
       [  2.97380679+2.24207754e-44j,  -5.74532523+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.83872342-1.57772181e-30j,   1.64638076-3.69778549e-31j,
         -0.56750495+1.57772181e-30j,  -5.74532523+7.88860905e-31j,
         66.4932094 +0.00000000e+00j, -10.70816264+2.56379794e-30j,
        -11.08111069+1.97215226e-31j,  -7.43474479-1.97215226e-31j,
          1.83872342+7.88860905e-31j, -10.70816264-1.57772181e-30j,
          1.86080059+2.69049305e-43j,   0.19541758+7.88860905e-31j,
          0.56304712+1.57772181e-30j,   1.64638076+3.20474743e-31j,
        -11.08111069+1.97215226e-31j,   0.19541758+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.96616419+4.48415509e-44j,   0.54752066-1.18329136e-30j,
         -0.56750495-1.57772181e-30j,  -7.43474479-3.94430453e-31j,
          0.56304712-1.57772181e-30j,   0.54752066+1.08468374e-30j,
          1.07252937+5.38098610e-43j],
       [  1.29893642+9.78011300e-36j,  -3.84386014+5.29395592e-23j,
         -1.86092176+9.92616735e-24j,  -4.21592632+1.32348898e-23j,
          1.03933803+6.61744490e-24j,  -3.84385976-6.61744490e-23j,
        -10.70816264+1.88079096e-36j,  31.76054462-5.29395592e-23j,
         -0.81206901+1.98523347e-23j,  -2.42506017-7.27918939e-23j,
         -1.8609219 -2.64697796e-23j,  31.76054419+2.64697796e-23j,
         -9.99217824+6.01853108e-36j,  -4.18589448-4.30133919e-23j,
         -2.25738823+0.00000000e+00j,  -4.21592646+0.00000000e+00j,
         -0.81206922-6.61744490e-24j,  -4.18589417+4.63221143e-23j,
          1.53827682+1.88079096e-37j,   1.02240603-1.45583788e-22j,
          1.03933832-6.61744490e-24j,  -2.42506066+7.27918939e-23j,
         -2.2573882 -1.32348898e-23j,   1.02240648+1.45583788e-22j,
          0.4993346 -1.20370622e-35j],
       [  1.31682879+9.02779661e-36j,  -4.65882716+3.30872245e-23j,
         -4.29572396+1.32348898e-23j,  -0.86792122+7.44462551e-24j,
          1.04359537+2.64697796e-23j,  -4.65882691-5.29395592e-23j,
        -11.08111069+3.00926554e-36j,  -0.81206926-5.29395592e-23j,
         32.00910946+1.32348898e-23j,  -2.29180333-6.61744490e-23j,
         -4.29572396-1.98523347e-23j,  -0.81206897+7.94093388e-23j,
          1.42042175+4.51389831e-36j,  -3.87247572-2.97785021e-23j,
          0.971801  -1.98523347e-23j,  -0.86792115-2.48154184e-24j,
         32.00910859-2.64697796e-23j,  -3.87247562+3.63959470e-23j,
        -10.69471254-9.40395481e-38j,  -2.38335511-7.94093388e-23j,
          1.04359555-1.32348898e-23j,  -2.29180342+7.27918939e-23j,
          0.97180114+0.00000000e+00j,  -2.38335456+1.19114008e-22j,
          0.51309298-3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -0.351662  -6.77084746e-36j,  -2.99673978-2.64697796e-23j,
          1.09027494-2.64697796e-23j,   0.99791231-3.30872245e-24j,
          0.38043531+6.61744490e-24j,  -2.99673969+2.64697796e-23j,
         -7.43474479-1.78675141e-36j,  -2.42506037+2.31610572e-23j,
         -2.29180337-4.96308368e-24j,   5.48456743+5.29395592e-23j,
          1.09027497+1.98523347e-23j,  -2.42506046-1.15805286e-23j,
          0.66133065-4.51389831e-36j,   2.08403436+3.63959470e-23j,
         -0.34767484-4.30133919e-23j,   0.99791231+4.96308368e-24j,
         -2.29180338+5.79026429e-24j,   2.08403451-1.32348898e-23j,
          0.53327358+1.03443503e-36j,  -0.33110204+7.23783036e-23j,
          0.38043522-6.61744490e-24j,   5.48456708-5.29395592e-23j,
         -0.34767495+3.97046694e-23j,  -0.33110231-7.63074115e-23j,
         -1.13338852+1.20370622e-35j],
       [ -9.15586255+1.50463277e-36j,  -4.54039273-4.13590306e-24j,
         32.72911818+4.96308368e-24j,  -1.85021376+1.65436123e-24j,
         -2.53702818-1.32348898e-23j,  -4.54039278-2.48154184e-24j,
          1.83872342+1.50463277e-36j,  -1.86092174+0.00000000e+00j,
         -4.29572395+0.00000000e+00j,   1.090275  +1.32348898e-23j,
         32.72911898-6.61744490e-24j,  -1.86092192+9.92616735e-24j,
         -9.24894513-5.64237288e-37j,  -4.93062949-9.92616735e-24j,
         -2.40960075-1.32348898e-23j,  -1.85021394-1.65436123e-24j,
         -4.29572397+0.00000000e+00j,  -4.93062942+6.61744490e-24j,
          1.40879764-3.76158192e-37j,   1.34936389-3.97046694e-23j,
         -2.53702773-1.65436123e-24j,   1.09027491-2.64697796e-23j,
         -2.40960071+6.61744490e-24j,   1.34936369+3.97046694e-23j,
          0.47563635-1.50463277e-35j],
       [  1.29893642-1.05324294e-35j,  -3.84385976-5.95570041e-23j,
         -1.8609219 -2.64697796e-23j,  -4.21592646-6.61744490e-24j,
          1.03933832+2.31610572e-23j,  -3.84386014+6.61744490e-23j,
        -10.70816264-3.38542373e-36j,  31.76054419+5.29395592e-23j,
         -0.81206922+1.98523347e-23j,  -2.42506066+5.95570041e-23j,
         -1.86092176+2.31610572e-23j,  31.76054462-7.94093388e-23j,
         -9.99217824-6.77084746e-36j,  -4.18589417+3.30872245e-23j,
         -2.2573882 +3.97046694e-23j,  -4.21592632+6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.81206901-1.32348898e-23j,  -4.18589448-4.63221143e-23j,
          1.53827682-1.12847458e-36j,   1.02240648+1.05879118e-22j,
          1.03933803+9.92616735e-24j,  -2.42506017-5.29395592e-23j,
         -2.25738823-1.32348898e-23j,   1.02240603-1.05879118e-22j,
          0.4993346 +0.00000000e+00j],
       [  2.36636534+8.96831017e-44j,  -0.51143448-1.57772181e-30j,
         -9.24894513-8.87468518e-31j,   1.17619748+3.94430453e-31j,
          0.42008941-7.95023881e-31j,  -0.51143448+2.36658272e-30j,
          1.86080059+1.79366203e-43j,  -9.99217824+1.77493704e-30j,
          1.42042175-7.88860905e-31j,   0.66133065+0.00000000e+00j,
         -9.24894513+5.91645679e-31j,  -9.99217824-1.18329136e-30j,
         64.80119411-1.79366203e-43j,  -5.84612899-1.08468374e-30j,
         -7.81047186+0.00000000e+00j,   1.17619748-5.91645679e-31j,
          1.42042175+0.00000000e+00j,  -5.84612899+1.77493704e-30j,
          3.7271156 -2.24207754e-44j,  -0.60817689+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.42008941+4.25245332e-31j,   0.66133065+0.00000000e+00j,
         -7.81047186+7.88860905e-31j,  -0.60817689+1.97215226e-31j,
          1.20175111+6.27781712e-43j],
       [ -0.57657211+1.50463277e-36j,  -6.96326969+2.64697796e-23j,
         -4.93062959+1.65436123e-24j,  -3.93042692-6.61744490e-24j,
          2.36685766+1.32348898e-23j,  -6.96326951-1.32348898e-23j,
          0.19541758+0.00000000e+00j,  -4.18589425+1.32348898e-23j,
         -3.87247569-1.98523347e-23j,   2.08403463-3.97046694e-23j,
         -4.93062931+3.30872245e-24j,  -4.1858944 -1.65436123e-23j,
         -5.84612899+3.00926554e-36j,  37.77920832+3.30872245e-24j,
         -3.01763347+0.00000000e+00j,  -3.93042706+9.92616735e-24j,
         -3.87247565+1.65436123e-23j,  37.77920777-1.65436123e-24j,
         -7.23213763+1.50463277e-36j,  -3.04026415+6.61744490e-24j,
          2.36685764-1.32348898e-23j,   2.08403425+3.97046694e-23j,
         -3.01763353+6.61744490e-24j,  -3.04026397-6.61744490e-24j,
          0.28030407+1.20370622e-35j],
       [  0.39917092+2.44502825e-36j,   2.14326495+1.07533480e-23j,
         -2.40960073+6.61744490e-24j,   1.17237044+1.34416850e-24j,
         -0.24619708+0.00000000e+00j,   2.14326504-8.27180613e-24j,
          0.56304712+1.59867232e-36j,  -2.25738823-1.65436123e-23j,
          0.97180111-6.61744490e-24j,  -0.34767488+9.92616735e-24j,
         -2.40960073+3.30872245e-24j,  -2.25738819+6.61744490e-24j,
         -7.81047186-4.70197740e-37j,  -3.01763354-4.96308368e-24j,
          5.63841366-1.32348898e-23j,   1.17237037-3.30872245e-24j,
          0.97180102+0.00000000e+00j,  -3.01763345+6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.46208872+1.88079096e-37j,   0.35404579-3.30872245e-23j,
         -0.24619711+0.00000000e+00j,  -0.34767491-6.61744490e-24j,
          5.6384134 +1.98523347e-23j,   0.35404595+4.30133919e-23j,
         -1.1998646 -3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -9.00198187-6.58276836e-36j,  -4.70636767-3.97046694e-23j,
         -1.85021388-2.15066959e-23j,  32.36796885+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.62837615-3.30872245e-24j,  -4.70636737+2.64697796e-23j,
          1.64638076+7.52316385e-37j,  -4.21592618+2.15066959e-23j,
         -0.86792107-1.98523347e-23j,   0.99791236+6.61744490e-23j,
         -1.85021382+2.64697796e-23j,  -4.2159266 -2.64697796e-23j,
          1.17619748-6.01853108e-36j,  -3.93042699+1.98523347e-23j,
          1.17237044-2.31610572e-23j,  32.3679699 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -0.86792129-1.32348898e-23j,  -3.93042699-1.65436123e-23j,
        -10.37559738+3.76158192e-37j,  -2.60535074+6.61744490e-23j,
         -2.62837621+3.30872245e-24j,   0.99791227-6.61744490e-23j,
          1.17237038+1.65436123e-23j,  -2.60535084-6.61744490e-23j,
          0.59574761+1.50463277e-36j],
       [  1.31682879-9.78011300e-36j,  -4.65882691-5.95570041e-23j,
         -4.29572396-6.61744490e-24j,  -0.86792115+4.96308368e-24j,
          1.04359555+0.00000000e+00j,  -4.65882716+4.63221143e-23j,
        -11.08111069-1.78675141e-36j,  -0.81206897+7.94093388e-23j,
         32.00910859+6.61744490e-24j,  -2.29180342+6.61744490e-23j,
         -4.29572396+2.64697796e-23j,  -0.81206926-6.61744490e-23j,
          1.42042175-7.52316385e-36j,  -3.87247562+2.64697796e-23j,
          0.97180114+6.61744490e-24j,  -0.86792122-4.96308368e-24j,
         32.00910946+1.32348898e-23j,  -3.87247572-3.30872245e-23j,
        -10.69471254-5.64237288e-37j,  -2.38335456+1.32348898e-22j,
          1.04359537+1.32348898e-23j,  -2.29180333-6.61744490e-23j,
          0.971801  -6.61744490e-24j,  -2.38335511-1.19114008e-22j,
          0.51309298+7.52316385e-36j],
       [ -0.57657211+0.00000000e+00j,  -6.96326951-1.32348898e-23j,
         -4.93062931+1.32348898e-23j,  -3.93042706+1.32348898e-23j,
          2.36685764-2.64697796e-23j,  -6.96326969+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.19541758+3.00926554e-36j,  -4.1858944 +1.98523347e-23j,
         -3.87247565+1.65436123e-23j,   2.08403425-2.64697796e-23j,
         -4.93062959-2.15066959e-23j,  -4.18589425-2.31610572e-23j,
         -5.84612899+0.00000000e+00j,  37.77920777+4.96308368e-24j,
         -3.01763353+2.64697796e-23j,  -3.93042692-9.92616735e-24j,
         -3.87247569-1.81979735e-23j,  37.77920832-6.61744490e-24j,
         -7.23213763-1.50463277e-36j,  -3.04026397-1.32348898e-23j,
          2.36685766+2.64697796e-23j,   2.08403463+1.98523347e-23j,
         -3.01763347-1.98523347e-23j,  -3.04026415-6.61744490e-24j,
          0.28030407-3.00926554e-36j],
       [  2.36648045+2.24207754e-44j,   0.72851489+7.88860905e-31j,
          1.40879764+5.91645679e-31j, -10.37559738+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.34120424-1.97215226e-31j,   0.72851489+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.96616419+0.00000000e+00j,   1.53827682+7.88860905e-31j,
        -10.69471254+3.94430453e-31j,   0.53327358-7.88860905e-31j,
          1.40879764-7.39557099e-31j,   1.53827682-5.42341872e-31j,
          3.7271156 +8.96831017e-44j,  -7.23213763+9.86076132e-31j,
         -0.46208872+3.94430453e-31j, -10.37559738+1.97215226e-31j,
        -10.69471254+0.00000000e+00j,  -7.23213763-1.38050658e-30j,
         66.67576266+2.24207754e-44j,  -7.36545725+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.34120424+1.97215226e-31j,   0.53327358+9.86076132e-31j,
         -0.46208872+3.94430453e-31j,  -7.36545725-3.94430453e-31j,
          1.10890059+0.00000000e+00j],
       [  0.28162   +5.26621469e-36j,   2.15291775+2.64697796e-23j,
          1.34936389+9.92616735e-24j,  -2.6053508 +0.00000000e+00j,
         -0.26687909+8.27180613e-24j,   2.15291739-2.64697796e-23j,
          0.54752066+7.52316385e-37j,   1.02240618-2.64697796e-23j,
         -2.38335482+1.65436123e-23j,  -0.33110235-3.97046694e-23j,
          1.34936369-1.65436123e-23j,   1.02240633+2.64697796e-23j,
         -0.60817689+3.00926554e-36j,  -3.04026407-9.92616735e-24j,
          0.35404585+3.97046694e-23j,  -2.60535078-1.65436123e-24j,
         -2.38335485-3.30872245e-24j,  -3.04026404+6.61744490e-24j,
         -7.36545725+0.00000000e+00j,   5.62390673-6.28657266e-23j,
         -0.26687921+4.13590306e-24j,  -0.33110199+5.29395592e-23j,
          0.35404589+0.00000000e+00j,   5.62390689+6.28657266e-23j,
         -1.18245232-3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -7.71376342-6.01853108e-36j,  -2.75237175-1.32348898e-23j,
         -2.5370281 -9.92616735e-24j,  -2.62837631+0.00000000e+00j,
          5.6962513 -1.32348898e-23j,  -2.75237237+1.98523347e-23j,
         -0.56750495-3.57350283e-36j,   1.03933817+2.64697796e-23j,
          1.04359542+1.32348898e-23j,   0.38043513+6.61744490e-24j,
         -2.53702781+9.92616735e-24j,   1.03933818+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.42008941-3.00926554e-36j,   2.3668577 +6.61744490e-24j,
         -0.24619695+5.29395592e-23j,  -2.62837605+3.30872245e-24j,
          1.0435955 +0.00000000e+00j,   2.3668576 -1.15805286e-23j,
          0.34120424-7.52316385e-37j,  -0.2668791 +8.93355062e-23j,
          5.69625179+6.61744490e-24j,   0.3804354 -1.32348898e-23j,
         -0.24619723-3.97046694e-23j,  -0.2668792 -8.27180613e-23j,
         -1.24019775+3.00926554e-36j],
       [ -0.351662  +6.77084746e-36j,  -2.99673969+3.97046694e-23j,
          1.09027497+1.32348898e-23j,   0.99791231+4.13590306e-24j,
          0.38043522-3.30872245e-24j,  -2.99673978-2.64697796e-23j,
         -7.43474479+1.12847458e-36j,  -2.42506046-2.81241408e-23j,
         -2.29180338+8.27180613e-25j,   5.48456708-5.29395592e-23j,
          1.09027494-1.32348898e-23j,  -2.42506037+2.31610572e-23j,
          0.66133065+4.51389831e-36j,   2.08403451-2.64697796e-23j,
         -0.34767495+4.63221143e-23j,   0.99791231-1.65436123e-24j,
         -2.29180337-8.27180613e-25j,   2.08403436+2.31610572e-23j,
          0.53327358-7.52316385e-37j,  -0.33110231-6.90695811e-23j,
          0.38043531+1.65436123e-24j,   5.48456743+5.29395592e-23j,
         -0.34767484-4.63221143e-23j,  -0.33110204+6.47268829e-23j,
         -1.13338852-9.02779661e-36j],
       [  0.39917092-9.40395481e-37j,   2.14326504-5.79026429e-24j,
         -2.40960073-3.30872245e-24j,   1.17237037+8.27180613e-25j,
         -0.24619711+0.00000000e+00j,   2.14326495+7.44462551e-24j,
          0.56304712-5.64237288e-37j,  -2.25738819+1.65436123e-23j,
          0.97180102+3.30872245e-24j,  -0.34767491-1.32348898e-23j,
         -2.40960073+3.30872245e-24j,  -2.25738823-9.92616735e-24j,
         -7.81047186-9.40395481e-38j,  -3.01763345+3.30872245e-24j,
          5.6384134 +1.98523347e-23j,   1.17237044-2.06795153e-24j,
          0.97180111-3.30872245e-24j,  -3.01763354-1.65436123e-24j,
         -0.46208872-5.64237288e-37j,   0.35404595+2.64697796e-23j,
         -0.24619708+0.00000000e+00j,  -0.34767488+1.32348898e-23j,
          5.63841366-1.98523347e-23j,   0.35404579-2.97785021e-23j,
         -1.1998646 +3.00926554e-36j],
       [  0.28162   -4.51389831e-36j,   2.15291739-2.64697796e-23j,
          1.34936369-1.98523347e-23j,  -2.60535078+1.65436123e-24j,
         -0.26687921-5.79026429e-24j,   2.15291775+1.98523347e-23j,
          0.54752066+0.00000000e+00j,   1.02240633+3.30872245e-23j,
         -2.38335485-1.32348898e-23j,  -0.33110199+2.64697796e-23j,
          1.34936389+1.65436123e-23j,   1.02240618-3.97046694e-23j,
         -0.60817689-3.00926554e-36j,  -3.04026404+6.61744490e-24j,
          0.35404589-3.97046694e-23j,  -2.6053508 +3.30872245e-24j,
         -2.38335482+1.98523347e-23j,  -3.04026407+0.00000000e+00j,
         -7.36545725+3.76158192e-37j,   5.62390689+6.94831715e-23j,
         -0.26687909+5.79026429e-24j,  -0.33110235+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.35404585+1.32348898e-23j,   5.62390673-6.12113653e-23j,
         -1.18245232+2.40741243e-35j],
       [  1.21720917+4.93257059e-43j,   0.2575331 +7.88860905e-31j,
          0.47563635+0.00000000e+00j,   0.59574761+0.00000000e+00j,
         -1.24019775+0.00000000e+00j,   0.2575331 -5.52202634e-30j,
          1.07252937-3.58732407e-43j,   0.4993346 +0.00000000e+00j,
          0.51309298-1.26217745e-29j,  -1.13338852-6.31088724e-30j,
          0.47563635-1.57772181e-30j,   0.4993346 -6.31088724e-30j,
          1.20175111+8.96831017e-43j,   0.28030407+9.46633086e-30j,
         -1.1998646 +1.26217745e-29j,   0.59574761+3.15544362e-30j,
          0.51309298+6.31088724e-30j,   0.28030407-3.15544362e-30j,
          1.10890059+0.00000000e+00j,  -1.18245232-3.15544362e-30j,
         -1.24019775+9.46633086e-30j,  -1.13338852+7.88860905e-30j,
         -1.1998646 -1.89326617e-29j,  -1.18245232+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.80359473-3.22859166e-42j]])
```

How do I suppress complex numbers within the calculation of `scipy.linalg.sqrtm()` so that the output matrix does not contain any complex numbers?

I did some googling around and found the following Github PR from 6 years ago which suggest to include function features like `funm_psd` and `structure="psd"` to evaluate general matrix functions of positive semi-definite matrices but I can't seem to find these functions features anywhere now.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3556

Any help would really be appreciated!

Edit:
I know I can use `np.real()` on the output matrix to get just the real part. My concern is including complex numbers **during** the calculation of the square root might affect the values in the output matrix, rather than just removing the complex numbers in the output matrix. Unless of course if including or excluding the complex numbers **during** the calculation of the square root won't affect much on the values of the output matrix. Would anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: Would you like just the real parts? Or would you likes 0s/nan values for sqrts of negative numbers?

Comment: Require just the real part, which I know I can use `np.real()` on the output matrix. But my concern is including complex numbers **during** the calculation of the square root might affect the values in the output matrix, rather than just removing the complex numbers in the output matrix. Unless of course if including or excluding the complex numbers **during** the calculation of the square root won't affect much on the values of the output matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I should also clarify that why I think the complex numbers are appearing is because of numerical precision/rounding issues with the implementation of the `scipy.linalg.sqrtm()` function (for eg. see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909814/how-to-avoid-complex-value-for-square-root-of-a-symmetric-matrix). For eg. values which are mathematically suppose to be zeros, have values like -7.52206733e-20 + 7.73635801e-19j where you can see has a complex part but the real part is very very close to zero.